# Need to use one field many times in one html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have two problems:
1- I need to enter more than one question in   ContentQue field. First click on "Add New Question" button then enter a question, click OK, show the data, then again click on  "Add New Question" button, but in this time the input is not shown?
2- I want to force the user to choose one module from select.

Thanks in advanced

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add New Item</title>
<style>
#myquelist
{
overflow-y:scroll;
}

// To force the user enter data
.btn
{
background-color:#336;
color:#CC6;
border-radius:10px;
padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
opacity:0.5;
}
.txt
{
background-color:#09F;
color:#009;
border-radius:10px;
}
.err
{
color:#F00;
}
</style>
<!-- Java Script-->
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnquestion').click(function () {
        $('#myquelist').hide('fast');
        $('#Type3').show('fast');
    });
    $('#btnOK').click(function () {
        var a=$('#ContentQue').val();
        var b=$('#qlist').val();
        var c=b+"<br>"+a;
        $('#qlist').val(c);
        $('#ContentQue').val('');
        document.getElementById("Type3").style.height="150px";
        document.getElementById("Type3").innerHTML=c;
        $('#myquelist').show('fast');
    });

    $('#myquelist').hide('fast');
    $('#Type3').hide('fast');
    $('#Type2').hide('fast');
    $('#ExamType1').click(function () {
        $('#Type2').hide('fast');
        $('#Type3').hide('fast');
        $('#Type1').show('fast');
    });
    $('#ExamType2').click(function () {
        $('#Type1').hide('fast');
        $('#Type3').hide('fast');
        $('#Type2').show('fast');
    });
        $('#ExamType3').click(function () {
        $('#Type1').hide('fast');
        $('#Type2').hide('fast');
        alert("A");         
        //$('#myquelist').show('fast');
        $('#Type3').show('fast');
    });


   // To force the user enter data in text box
    $(" :text" ).addClass("txt"); 
    $("p").hide();  
    $("#PageBody input:text select").blur(function()
    {
        if(!$(this).val())    
        {
            $(this).parent("div").children("p").show();   
            $(this).parent("div").children("p").addClass("err");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent("div").children("p").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body id="PageBody">
<header><h2>New Exam</h2></header>
<form id="form1">
<table  width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="5px">
<tr>
<th><b>Assignment Title : 
<td><div><input type="text" name="ExamTitle" autofocus ><p>Please Exam Title</p></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><b>Exam Type</b></th>
<td> 
<input type="radio" name="ExamType" value="File"   id="ExamType1" checked="checked">File
<input type="radio" name="ExamType" value="Text" id="ExamType2">Text
<input type="radio" name="ExamType" value="Questions" id="ExamType3">Questions
<div id="Type1">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</div> 
<div id="Type2">
<input type="text"  name="ContentText"  class="hidden" autofocus>
</div> 
<div id="myquelist">
<button id="btnquestion" type="button" name="AddNew" class="hidden">Add New Question</button>
</div> 
<div id="Type3">
<input type="text" id="ContentQue"  name="ContentQue" >
<button type="button" id="btnOK"  name="OK" >OK</button>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="qlist" name="qlist">
</td> 
</tr>
<tr>    
<th><b>Module :</b></th>
<td>
<select id="Modl" name="Modl" >
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" >Choose Module</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="D">D</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- Other inputs -->
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="2">
<input type="submit" name="SaveBtn"  style="width:95px;height:50px"; value="Save" />
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
<?php 

$qlist = $_POST["qlist"];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Created a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ax2zds1o/

Comment: Twisty, In JSFiddle is working but in my localhost is not. Sorry for make you busy with my code, and for my bad English language

Comment: Please ensure Jquery is loading. What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: I solved the problem by moving "});" down. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needed a fair amount of work. I had to clean up a few HTML issues and change the logic some.

First, much easier to use an Array to store the various questions. I would pass the array to your form handler, but I populated the `qlist` as you were shooting for.

Second, to show the questions, I used a List. Easier to work with later.

Third, I wrapped the different parts so they are easier to hide/show.

Fourth, I added in verification that a user entered a question when clicking `ok` and when they submit the form, to ensure they selected a Module.

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <h2>New Exam</h2>
</header>
<form id="form1">
  <table width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="5px">
    <tr>
      <th width="135px"><b>Assignment Title : </b></th>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="ExamTitle" autofocus />
          <p>Please Exam Title</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th height="80px"><b>Exam Type :</b></th>
      <td valign="top">
        <input type="radio" name="ExamType" value="File" id="ExamType1" checked="checked" />File
        <input type="radio" name="ExamType" value="Text" id="ExamType2" />Text
        <input type="radio" name="ExamType" value="Questions" id="ExamType3" />Questions
        <div id="Type1">
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        </div>
        <div id="Type2">
          <input type="text" name="ContentText" class="hidden" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div id="Type3">
          <div id="addNew">
            <button id="btnquestion" type="button" name="AddNew" class="hidden">Add New Question</button>
          </div>
          <div id="addQuestion" style="display: none;">
            <input type="text" id="ContentQue" name="ContentQue">
            <button type="button" id="btnOK" name="OK">OK</button>
          </div>
          <div id="showQuestions" style="display: none;">
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" id="qlist" name="qlist">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><b>Module :</b></th>
      <td>
        <select id="Modl" name="Modl">
          <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose Module</option>
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
          <option value="C">C</option>
          <option value="D">D</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Other inputs -->
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="SaveBtn" style="width:95px;height:50px;" value="Save" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
  background-color: #336;
  color: #CC6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.txt {
  background-color: #09F;
  color: #009;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.err {
  color: #F00;
}

#Type3 ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#Type3 ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
// Set Globals
var ql = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Set View State
  $("#Type1").show();
  $("#Type2").hide();
  $("#Type3").hide();

  // Set Action Functions
  $('#btnquestion').click(function() {
    $('#addNew').hide();
    $('#addQuestion').show();
    $("#ContentQue").focus();
  });

  $('#btnOK').click(function() {
    var q;
    q = $('#ContentQue').val();
    if (q == "") {
      alert("Please enter a Question.");
      $("#ContentQue").focus();
      return false;
    }
    ql.push(q);
    $('#qlist').val(ql.join(","));
    $('#ContentQue').val('');
    if (ql.length > 0) {
      var qtext = $("<ul>");
      $.each(ql, function(i, v) {
        qtext.append("<li id='que-" + i + "'>" + v + "</li>");
      });
      $("#showQuestions").html(qtext);
    }
    $("#addQuestion").hide();
    $('#showQuestions').show();
    $("#addNew").show();
  });

  $("#form1 input[name='ExamType']").click(function() {
    var pick = $(this).val();
    switch (pick) {
      case "File":
        $("#Type1").show();
        $("#Type2").hide();
        $("#Type3").hide();
        break;
      case "Text":
        $("#Type1").hide();
        $("#Type2").show();
        $("#Type3").hide();
        break;
      case "Questions":
        $("#Type1").hide();
        $("#Type2").hide();
        $("#Type3").show();
        break;
    }
  });
});

$("#form1").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($("#Modl option").eq(0).is(":selected")){
    alert("Please select a Module.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ax2zds1o/6/

Things you may want to consider:

1. A button to remove a question from the list
2. How many questions do you want to allow? 100? 200? 1000? How will you pass a large number of questions?
3. Allowing the user to arrange the order of the questions in the list before submitting

Comment: hey @Twisty nice answer and great tagline!

Comment: Heh nice! "Important Things!"

Comment: Waw, It is exactly what I want. Only one thing is when user choose Questions, suppose the input box and OK button are shown by default. Many thanks Twisty

Comment: The select part is not working. Is there any way to check before submit the form like what I did for the text input?    $(" :text" ).addClass("txt"); 
  $("p").hide(); 
  $("#PageBody input:text select").blur(function()
  {
   if(!$(this).val())    
   {
    $(this).parent("div").children("p").show();   
    $(this).parent("div").children("p").addClass("err");
   }
   else
   {
    $(this).parent("div").children("p").hide();
   }
  });

Comment: @Marmar you can adjust this by adjusting the Show/Hide or `display:none` portions for the Input box & button. Yes, you can add a selector for the select, like you did for other stuff, BUT if the user never changes it or focuses on it and submits the form, none of those would be activated. This is why I bounded the verification to the form submission.

Comment: Yes Twisty I am doing the adjustment. But the validation that you did for  select part is not working, I can submit the form and no alert popup!

Comment: I tested it thoroughly, it was not working for me at first and then I realized it's `#Modl` and not `#Mod1`. If you can fork/update the JSFiddle with the code you're using, I can look at it.